# Utilizar formulario que corresponde a otro controlador

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### Contexto

1. Se crea formulario a travez de comando

   ```
   $ rails g scaffold Cotizacion
   ```
2. Se instala plantilla desde https://startbootstrap.com/

#### Objetivo y problema

La idea es integrar el formulario `new`, que crea una nueva cotización a la plantilla de bootstrap.

Entendiendo que estoy tratando de usar un formulario que corresponde a otro controlador.

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente. Se esta intentando llamar al formulario *_form.html.erb* de la vista *cotizacions*, desde el archivo *index.html.erb* correspondiente a la vista *creatives*. Ambas vistas ocupan controladores distintos (¿se podrá realizar eso?)

Invocación a formulario desde *index.html.erb*:

```
<%= render :partial =>'cotizaciones/form' , cotizacion: @cotizacion%>
<%= render 'navbar' %>
<%= render 'header' %>
<%= render 'services' %>
<%= render 'portfolio' %>
<%= render 'call_to_action' %>
<%= render 'contact' %>
```

El mensaje desplegado por la aplicación al levantar la pagina es el siguiente:

> undefined local variable or method `cotizacion' for
>   <#:0x007fcae29cb080> Did you mean?  cotizacion_url
>
> Extracted source (around line #1):
>
> ```
>       <%= form_with(model: cotizacion, local: true) do |form| %>
>       <%= form_with(model: cotizacion, local: true) do |form| %>
>       <% if cotizacion.errors.any? %>
>       <div id="error_explanation">
>       <h2><%= pluralize(cotizacion.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited 
>        this cotizacion from being saved:</h2>
> ```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido.. por lo que veo a tu respuesta le falta un pedazo. puedas [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/88642/edit) para que este completa?

Comment: Parece que la pregunta esta incompleta pero al parecer el contexto de @cotizacion queda en nil ya que la plantilla se aplica a todas tus vistas, podrías probar con cotización: Cotizacion.new igual te recomendaría usar nombres de modelos en ingles ya que ActiveRecord y otras gemas usan los plurales en ingles.

Comment: listo, espero que se comprenda la pregunta Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que no está reconociendo la variable `cotizacion` debido a que estás realizando la asignación de manera incorrecta: para pasar variables a un `partial` debes utilizar el atributo `locals`.

Para solucionarlo simplemente asigna la variable `cotizacion` utilizando el atributo `locals`:

```
<%= render partial: 'cotizaciones/form', locals: { cotizacion: @cotizacion } %>
```

O bien, como opción alterna, puedes eliminar el uso del atributo `partial` y así podrás pasar la variable tal como lo estabas haciendo:

```
<%= render 'cotizaciones/form', cotizacion: @cotizacion %>
```

Las dos opciones generan el mismo resultado por lo que recomiendo utilizar la segunda (es más corta), sin embargo utiliza la que se te resulte más sencilla/intuitiva y se consistente en su uso a lo largo de tu aplicación.